# I can't view or add comments

Tags: php

Hey, there. I just got this site up and going. http://www.paledogstudios.com It works fine except for the fact I can't seem to see past comments (this blog was imported from blogger) or add comments.

I know it's the code not the settings since someone else told me but he didn't help me further.

He said it was probably on the index.php

Help?

Comment: do you have a comments.php in your theme folder? if yes, can you pastebin the code?

Comment: http://wordpress.pastebin.com/f5ZL99Cs

Comment: I think the error is in your index.php file (see my answer). can you pastebin the code of this file?

Comment: The error is in your theme index.php file. Have you check that out already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your posts titles do not link to the single post pages, they link to the archive page. By example, the lastest article "It really is that small" links to "http://www.paledogstudios.com/2010/10/04/".

The error should be in your theme index.php file.

Comment: I changed the permalink to default and now it works! Thank you so much!

I don't know if you're up for it but I'm up for drawing you a free art commission for helping me out! If you're interested just message me the info!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things, you're missing a call to `comments_template()` in your files.  I wouldn't recommend putting this in `index.php` (that's the file that generates your entire list of blogs ... listing comments there would make your page *huge*).

What you want to do is add `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in your `single.php` file (the template file for Single Posts) before `<?php endwhile; ?>`.

So an example from the TwentyTen theme:

```
    </div><!-- #post-## -->

    <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '</span>' ); ?></div>
    </div><!-- #nav-below -->

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

You can see they're placing the comment block after contextual navigation but before the loop closes.  This is what you'll want to do in your own theme as well.

Comment: I do have that in the code Here's the single.php code http://wordpress.pastebin.com/CqPRQ837

Comment: In that case, my next guess would be that a plug-in is disabling your comment box.  The comments are obviously there (as seen by your footer icon widgets), but these same plug-ins might be disabling the display.  Try disabling all of your plug-ins to see if comments show up again.  If they do, start turning things back on one-by-one to find the culprit.

Comment: I turned them all off. Still nothing! :( Man this is so weird

Comment: Do you have comments enabled in your WordPress settings?  Settings >> Discussion >> "Allow people to post comments on new articles" ...

Comment: Yep http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3193/helpn.jpg

Comment: *@nalem* I just sent you a message via gmail ...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that enabling comments or Disqus at a time, will not affect old posts. You should add new posts afterward to allow commenting or go to *Setting -> Posts -> Quick Edit*, to allow comments on a particular post or take a bulk edit action to allow comments on all older posts.

Is commenting for the affected pages closed within WordPress itself? To determine this:

1. Navigate to your WordPress *Dashboard > Posts > click Quick Edit* on an affected post
2. Make sure the “*Allow comments*” checkbox is enabled

If comments are enabled within WordPress, a thread can be opened by clicking the “Open thread” link in the thread’s Settings dropdown in the Disqus embed on your site. For reference, here’s a screenshot:

[image]